# How to hosting Asp.Net 5 web api in Windows 10 iot core without Powershell

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, win-universal-app, dnx, windows-10-iot-core

I published a web api on pi2 then run command ".\web.cmd" via Powershell remotely, but I want to make the site run automatically without using Powershell.

Is there another way to run my asp.net web api automatically?

**.net core version**

*dnx-coreclr-win-arm.1.0.0-rc2-16357*

**commands**

*Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls=http://*:5000/*

Comment: look at [schtasks.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to schedule starting the task automatically

Comment: thank you very much!! 
I created a schdule task:

schtasks /create /tn "My Web Api" /tr c:\PROGRAMS\approot\web.cmd /sc onstart /ru System

it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `schtasks.exe` to schedule a task to start when the system starts.